AWS Cognito Change Field names on Managed Login
I cannot find documentation on AWS Cognito to change the new Managed Login pages to edit field names on user signup.  I want to require name fields, but change to First Name and Last Name instead of Given/Family name.  I see now way to do this in the AWS UI.  Adding custom fields does not make it required, so the custom attributes do not seem to work for me. How can I just modify these labels on the UI?


Field names such as Username, Password, or Email cannot be changed through Cognito's native options but you can use AWS Amplify or create your own login page cognito.
Here you can see all the possible UI customization that are available by AWS Cognito : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/what-is-amazon-cognito.html
And this documentation for apply branding to managing loggin page :
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/managed-login-branding.html#:~:text=In%20the%20Amazon%20Cognito%20console%2C%20new%20user%20pools,switch%20between%20managed%20login%20and%20hosted%20UI%20branding.
I have also found this videos that can perhaps help you : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8WZmIdXZe3Q&t=182s
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VWS-Nue1yX4
